# SQL Query trouble filtering out Sums

Tags: sql

I need help figuring out how to refine the following SQL query from an Oracle Database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    PR.DOC_ID, PR.AMEND_NO, LEDGER.ACCT_ID, APPRVL_CHAIN.APPRVR, 
    SUM(LEDGER.COMMIT)
FROM 
    LUFSMGR.APPRVL_CHAIN APPRVL_CHAIN, 
    LUFSMGR.LEDGER LEDGER, 
    LUFSMGR.PR PR
WHERE 
    PR.DOC_ID = LEDGER.DOC_ID 
    AND LEDGER.DOC_ID = APPRVL_CHAIN.DOC_ID 
    AND APPRVL_CHAIN.AMEND_NO = LEDGER.AMEND_NO 
    AND LEDGER.AMEND_NO = PR.AMEND_NO 
    AND ((PR.DOC_ID Like '2116%') 
         AND (LEDGER.ACCT_ID Like '25601 105300SD%') 
         AND (APPRVL_CHAIN.APPRVR_ROLE='Funds Manager'))
GROUP BY 
    PR.DOC_ID, PR.AMEND_NO, LEDGER.ACCT_ID, APPRVL_CHAIN.APPRVR
HAVING 
    (SUM(LEDGER.COMMIT) <> 0)
ORDER BY 
    PR.DOC_ID
```

This results in data whose sample looks like this:

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/831d5.jpg)

I need to filter out all Doc_ID where the sum of commitments including amendments is = 0.  For example Doc_ID 21162465SD541 should be filtered out since the sum of Ammend_No 0,1,and 2 are 0.

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

If you want information at the document level, then only include that in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT PR.DOC_ID, Sum(LEDGER.COMMIT)
FROM LUFSMGR.APPRVL_CHAIN APPRVL_CHAIN JOIN
     LUFSMGR.LEDGER LEDGER
     ON LEDGER.DOC_ID = APPRVL_CHAIN.DOC_ID AND APPRVL_CHAIN.AMEND_NO = LEDGER.AMEND_NO JOIN
     LUFSMGR.PR PR
     ON PR.DOC_ID = LEDGER.DOC_ID AND  AND LEDGER.AMEND_NO = PR.AMEND_NO 
WHERE (PR.DOC_ID Like '2116%') AND
      (LEDGER.ACCT_ID Like '25601 105300SD%') AND 
      (APPRVL_CHAIN.APPRVR_ROLE = 'Funds Manager')
GROUP BY PR.DOC_ID
HAVING Sum(LEDGER.COMMIT) <> 0
ORDER BY PR.DOC_ID;
```

Notes:

- Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Using `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` is almost never the right thing to do.

Comment: The challenge is that I still need the Ammend_No, Account_ID and APPRVR for the Documents that that do not have a total commitment of 0.

Comment: You can use a `JOIN` or `IN` with this query to get additional detail.